# Add a row to the DATAGrid for every click on the button

Tags: c#, wpf

For every click on the button, I need to add the list contents to the new row of the Data Grid View in WPF.

The below was the code, but it was not giving the exact behaviour.

```
public class DisplayTable
{
    public int AnalyteId { get; set; }
    public int UnitCode { get; set; }
    public int ReferenceValue { get; set; }

}


    DisplayTable d = new DisplayTable();
    List<DisplayTable> list = new List<DisplayTable>();
    private void btnAddAnalyte_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (CheckBox item in this.AnalyteLitst.Items)
        {

            if (item.IsChecked == true)
            {
                d.AnalyteId = 1;

            }
        }


        foreach (CheckBox unit in this.UnitsList.Items)
        {


            if (unit.IsChecked == true)
            {
                d.UnitCode = 12;

            }

        }
        list.Add(d);
        dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGrid.IsReadOnly = false;

        dataGrid.RowHeight = 30;
        dataGrid.ColumnWidth = 100;
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
        dataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true;

  }
```

Comment: @KarthikVenkatraman, row with data.

Comment: 1. `List<DisplayTable> list` should be `ObservableCollection<DisplayTable> list` because ObservableCollection can notify DataGrid about new items added 2. `DisplayTable d = new DisplayTable();` should be inside btnAddAnalyte_Click method because the goal is to add **new** row, not to repeat the same item multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Set `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` *once* in the constructor of the view. Also set it to `ObservableCollection<DisplayTable>` and add new objects to this one in your event handler:

```
ObservableCollection<DisplayTable> list = new ObservableCollection<DisplayTable>();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGrid.IsReadOnly = false;
    dataGrid.RowHeight = 30;
    dataGrid.ColumnWidth = 100;
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
    dataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true;
}

private void btnAddAnalyte_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayTable d = new DisplayTable();
    foreach (CheckBox item in this.AnalyteLitst.Items)
    {
        if (item.IsChecked == true)
        {
            d.AnalyteId = 1;
        }
    }

    foreach (CheckBox unit in this.UnitsList.Items)
    {
        if (unit.IsChecked == true)
        {
            d.UnitCode = 12;
        }
    }
    list.Add(d);
}
```